# Xcode 3.2.3 (SDK 4) cannot support device iPod touch (iOS 4.1) and iPad (iOS 3.2.2)

Tags: ipad, ios4, ipod-touch, device-emulation

I cant do test apps on my devices. Following are screenshots.

iPod:
[image]

iPad:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 4.1 iPod, you just need to [download the latest SDK](https://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.1__final/xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1.dmg), as the screenshot is telling you.

For the iPad, you will need to update the device to iOS 4.1, and download the 4.1 SDK.

Comment: is there any alternative for iPod 4.1? what about iPad?

Comment: There is no alternative.  Is there any reason you are unable to download the SDK?  I know it's big, and yes it's annoying that you have to download Xcode again along with the SDK, but you just have to bite the bullet.

Comment: As for iPad, see the new 2nd paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OS Installed on  apple 的 iPad
3.2.2 (7B500)

Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
4.0 (8A293)
3.2
3.1.3
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1
3.0.1
3.0

My XCode3.2.3 SDK4.0final ,Ipad 3.2.2 。the screenshot is the same to above.

I need  the SDK 4.1?